# Can we use vector in c++ to take user input of unknown size only till we hit enter?

Tags: c++, vector

I was trying to take user input in a vector in c++, as vector is a dynamic data structure i wanted it to take input as long as user wants and when the user hit enter key it should stop taking the input (just as a string) only difference i want to do it in an integer vector, but i am unable to do so let me know if it is possible or not to take user input in a vector like the way i described.

I have searched the web for various ways but still my code isn't running the way i want, I have tried breaking the loop of input by using `EOF` symbols but it is not stopping the loop of input.
I have tried using `cin.ignore()` function but it also takes spacebar in count
i only want to stop input when enter key is pressed. 
below is the most recent code i made:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
vector<int> v;
char c;
for(int i=0;;i++){
    cin>>c;
    if(c=='\n'){
        break;
    }
    int x = c - '0';// typecasting char into integer.
    v.push_back(x);
}
cout<<v.size()<<endl;// just to check if it is done taking input and what is the size of vector now.
}
```

Comment: *"but i am unable to do so "* and *" it didn't quite work"* You will have to clarify these statements. Why aren't you able to do so? What didn't work? Please describe the nature of the problem you've encountered.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux understand and have edited it, sorry if the question was unclear for any reason that's my first question asked by the way so may be i failed to clarify it, but now i think it should be clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::getline()` to get the entire line and then `std::istreamstream` to get the integers into a vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {

    std::string input;

    std::getline( std::cin, input );

    std::istringstream is( input );

    std::vector<int> v( ( std::istream_iterator<int>( is ) ), std::istream_iterator<int>() );

    std::cout << v.size() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the entire line as string and build each number. Something like that:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s; getline(cin, s);
    int num = 0;
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
        if(s[i] == ' ')
            v.push_back(num), num = 0;
        else
            num = num*10 + (s[i]-'0');
    v.push_back(num);

    cout << v.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Answers consisting only of code are considered incomplete. Please explain what the original problem was and how this fixes it.

Comment: The goal appears to be to read input until enter is pressed. This code will not accomplish this, it will read a single `int` per line break until an input not convertible to `int` is found or until the stream otherwise fails.

Comment: Manually building the numbers is probably a very bad idea.

Comment: @MartinYork. Maybe you do not remember the `std :: istreamstream` parameters and in my experience in Competitive Programming is useful the manual building

Comment: `operator>>` will read a number. A building the wheel again is not a useful exercise as you will not gain the benefit or 60 years of bug fixing that has been applied to the standard library to create the perfect wheel for reading a number. Also the maintenance cost of this is excessively high the next person is going to say ehhhhhhh why on earth is this done like that. Then spend 2 minutes removing your bug and putting in the correct code.

Comment: @ivangalban 1) `Maybe you do not remember the std :: istreamstream parameters` Nobody remembers everything, google it, 2) `in Competitive Programming is useful the manual building` Competitive Programming is a joke so... 3) Whenever C++ offers you something, take it. Don't over-complicate things for no reason.

Comment: @DimChtz, MartinYork, I understand your point, you are right. I had the same problem years ago and that was my solution.
I agree, is't not clean, understandable, although solve the problem.
I shared my solution and I learned another better ;)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to input Vector elements as a single string and use Stringstream function to assign elements in increasing order of vector's indices respectively.
Here's the code :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    string buffer;
    int data;
    getline(cin,buffer);
    istringstream iss(buffer);
    while(iss>>data){
        v.push_back(data);
    }
    cout<<v.size()<<" ";
    cout<<"Vector Elements"<<endl;
    for(int k=0;k<v.size();k++){
        cout<<v[k]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. When you read from std::cin, it will accept an entire line from the console. Your cin>>c will retrieve the first character of the line and put that character into the variable c.
2. This means your if(c=='\n') is pretty much pointless since the line will be consumed and you won't see an explicit '\n' as the first character...EVER.
3. c - '0' will convert a single ASCII character that is a digit (i.e. 0123456789) to a number you can use, but that is NOT typecasting a char into an integer. That's converting an ASCII character that happens to be a number into a numeric value. A type cast is when you change the TYPE of a value to another TYPE.
4. I *think* you want to do something like the following...

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <conio.h>

   int main( int cArguments, const char** apszArguments ) {
       std::vector<char> vchars;
       char c;

       do {
         c = getche();
         vchars.push_back( c );
       } while( c != '\n' );

       std::cout << vchars.size() << " characters received" << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Note that on macOS and some Linux variants, getch/getche are not defined and you'll need to use termios or ncurses functions instead.